# Using proxy to run a javascript function on external webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

As the title suggests, I need to run a function on a external site.
I understand the basics of cross-origin, so I know I'd need a proxy.

Is it possible to run a proxy on the server (php?) that would load the webpage, and then run a function, get the returned value and send it to the client?

If so, how would I do this?

Since I don't own a server per se, I think I'd have to resort to php due to me only owning a webserver.

Comment: Php dos not have a javascript engine, so cannot run javascript code. Either you need to use something that can run javascript (eg a headless browser like phantomjs), or you will have to rewrite the javascript function in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not able to do that in PHP, as it cannot parse the javascript as a client would. You would need a headless browser, like [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) and develop a script to control the browser (you could use [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)). Your PHP script can then return the value to the client.

Comment: Alright, this sounds like a possibility if I use a free product like heroku. Thanks a lot!
EDIT: I don't see anything about running a function in the documentation of php-phantomjs. Is that something I'd have to program myself?

Comment: If it is a javascript function, then use [evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) in phantomjs. In PHP-phantomjs it would be [writing a custom template](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/4-custom-scripts/#writing-a-custom-template).